# Smoothing image edges in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, image, antialiasing

I have a few 256x256 images I am using with Image controls in a WPF application. Although they are all 256x256, I changed some of the controls to 64x64, etc. When I resize it down (using fill as my stretch property), the edges become very rough. Even on something as simple as a triangle, it is painfully apparent:

[image]

Is there a good fix for this, or do i need to resize the images in photoshop before putting them into the application?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You need to set the Image's render options.

Try setting the style of the Image to:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Image">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="64" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="64" />
        <Setter Property="RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode" Value="HighQuality" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

To use the image, simply call as before:

```
<Image Source="/Images/MyImage.png" />
```

Or, to use the `RenderOptions` on a single image:

```
<Image RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality"
       Source="/Images/MyImage.png"
       Width="64"
       Height="64" />
```

For more info see:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.renderoptions.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Here is previous answer in code:

```
var i = new Image();
System.Windows.Media.RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(i, System.Windows.Media.BitmapScalingMode.HighQuality);
```